# word count in c with errors

Tags: c, linux

I´m a beginner in C for Linux, and I need help because my program doesn´t work and I don´t see the problem.

This is my program, this program counts words, lines, and letters from the standard input. But doesn't count when there is a `' '`, `'\t'` or `'\n'`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void panic (char *str){
    char s [100];
    sprintf (s, "%s (%d %s)\n", str, errno, strerror (errno));
    write (222, s, strlen (s));
    exit (1);
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    char c;
    unsigned lines =1;
    int n;
    int letters =0;
    int words =0;
    int countLin=0;
    int countLet=0;
    char resultLine=[100];


    while ((n = read (0, &c, 1))> 0){
        if(c!=' '&&c!='\t'&&c!='\n'){
        letters++;
        if(countLet!=0){
            words++;
            countLet=0;
        }
        if(countLin!=0){
            lines++;
            words++;
            countLin=0;
        } 
    }
        if(c==' '||c=='\t')
            countLet++;
        if(c=='\n')
            countLin++;
    }
    if (n<0)
        panic ("Read");
    sprintf (resultLine, "%d %d %d \n", lines, words, letters);
    if(write(1,resultLine, strlen(resultLine))<0)
        panic("Write");
    return (0);
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should learn to compile with warnings and debugging information, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g yoursource.c -o yourprog`, improve the code till no warnings are given, and then debug your program with `gdb yourprog` and you should use `getchar` instead of `read`-ing characters one at a time.

Comment: `char resultLine=[100];` `write (222, s, strlen (s));`

How do end the input? Ctrl+C?

Comment: So what's the problem you're seeing right now?

Comment: I am unaware of this syntax:    char resultLine=[100]; I usually write  char resultLine[100];

Comment: i send the file with <, for example ./program< file

Comment: /usr/include/string.h:397: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
prueba1.c:44: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘write’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/unistd.h:363: note: expected ‘const void *’ but        argument is of type ‘char’
     prueba1.c:47: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

Comment: muky@muky-desktop:~$ gcc -Wall -g prueba1.c -o prueba
prueba1.c: In function ‘main’:
prueba1.c:21: error: expected expression before ‘[’ token
prueba1.c:43: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sprintf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/stdio.h:341: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char’
prueba1.c:44: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Is there a question here? "doesn't work" is not a compiler diagnostic.

Comment: "my errors are " ... so fix them. These are all compilation errors.

Comment: OK, I see one mystake `char resultLine=[100];`, now i put `char resultLine [100] `. But there is other problem.

Comment: Ok, my question is about sprintf, write and read. Because is the first time that i writing a code with them and i need help.

Comment: Type `man sprintf` and `man 2 read` to learn about `sprintf` function and `read` syscall. You might need the `manpages` and `manpages-dev` packages. See also http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
char resultLine=[100];
```

to:

```
char resultLine[100];
```

Comment: Yes, I change this but there is other problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the order of these two lines:

```
    if(c!=' '&&c!='\t'&&c!='\n'){
        letters++;
    ...
    }
```

otherwise `letters` won't be incremented for whitespace characters